# Assigning hex value to 32bit signed INT in C++

Tags: c++, variables

I have downloaded some code from the Interwebs and attempted to compile it.  Unfortunately it fails to compile with many of the following errors:

```
error: narrowing conversion of ‘2567524794’ from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘int32_t’ {aka ‘int’} [-Wnarrowing]
```

I had a look at the code:

```
int32_t crc_table[256] = {
            0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c, 0x990951ba, 0x076dc419, 0x706af48f, 0xe963a535, 0x9e6495a3,
            0x0edb8832, 0x79dcb8a4, 0xe0d5e91e, 0x97d2d988, 0x09b64c2b, 0x7eb17cbd, 0xe7b82d07, 0x90bf1d91}
```

From what I understand, crc_table is declared as a signed INT and the compiler is interpreting the hex value as being unsigned and refusing to do it.

NB: I'm not a C++ developer, just someone trying to compile someone else's code, so my C++ powers are weak

I did have go at converting the HEX to signed decimal but that didn't really help, quite possible I did a bad job of the conversion.

I wonder actually what the correct way to fix this is?  Can one assign a hex value to a signed INT or does one have to use a different format?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot change the type of the array to e.g.: `uint32_t`?

Comment: You ***can*** assign a hex value to a signed int. In fact that's the first choice of the compiler, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal (section "The type of the literal"); The issue here is that the compiler does choose a 32 but unsigned int here rather than a 32 bit signed int, since `0x990951ba` does not fit a 32 bit signed int; the highest value that would fit is `0x7FFFFFFF`

Comment: Also note that there is no such thing as a negative integer literal in C++. Stuff like `int a = -42;` applies the unary minus operator to the *positive* integer constant.

Comment: I assume it was declared as a 32bit signed int since it was expected to hold values including the range -32768 to 0.  I think that rather than seeing numbers > 0x7FFFFFFF as being > 32,768, the developer was expecting the compiler to interpret it as a negative number.  I did try converting the numbers to decimal, which allowed the program to compile but not run properly.  I also tried the suggestion above to changing ti to unsigned but again it failed.  I expect I screwed up the conversion.